# How to set iOS 13 dark mode large title color?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios13, ios-darkmode, large-title

In my app i use

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.SFProDisplay(ofSize: 34, weight: .bold),
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.custom
]

static var custom: UIColor {
    return UIColor(named: "color_custom")!
}
```

[image: color set]

where have a color set `color_custom`.
But when switching between color modes it used only Any Appearance color. Dark Appearance not used. Why?

**ADDITION:**

After some research i figured that should add to the question next: In my app i use a switcher to switch between modes.
`Storage.isDarkModeOn = newState // saving in user defaults`. Then:

```
class PapaViewController: UIViewController {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = Storage.isDarkModeOn ? .dark : .light
    }
}
```

Where PapaViewController is a parent class for all UIViewControllers in my app. So if `overrideUserInterfaceStyle == .dark` and device color mode == `.light` the bug shows up. If then i change the device color mode to `.dark` then large title looks as expected.

Comment: Your code is working. Didn't you forget to call the `appearance` function?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini nope. It is working in light color mode as needed.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The large title switches colors just fine for me. Please show enough code _in context_ to allow the problem to be reproduced - not just the little snippets you _think_ are enough.

Comment: @matt what else you need? Thats only code is rely to problem, placed in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: What else do _you_ need? Would you like me to post an example project proving that your code works just fine? I mean, of course I don't know what `UIFont.SFProDisplay` means, but everything else I can just copy and use directly and the large title changes color as expected. (I used Georgia as the font instead.)

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/mattneub/LargeTitleTest Download. Run. Change between dark and light modes. Look.

Comment: @matt thanks for your time. I did add more explanation to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code you've shown *now* is merely that you're talking to the wrong view controller. It is not *your* view controller (`self`) whose `override` you need to change: it is the *root* view controller, which in this case is probably the navigation controller.

```
class PapaViewController: UIViewController {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated https://github.com/mattneub/LargeTitleTest to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using iOS 13's new appearance API?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance

Example:

```
let style = UINavigationBarAppearance()
style.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font: #YOURFONT#]

navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = style
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = ...
navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = ...
```